# How to host Angular 4 multi-language on Apache?

Tags: angular, apache, multilingual

I have a website that uses both English and French. I use the following command to build the application:

```
ng build --output-path=dist/fr --aot --prod --bh /fr/ --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.fr.xlf --i18n-format=xlf --locale=fr
ng build --output-path=dist/en --aot --prod --bh /en/
```

I copy both `en` and `fr` folders to the web root. Each folder has its own `.htaccess` as following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /crisis-center/
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

I also added a `.htaccess` to the web root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /crisis-center/
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]
  RewriteRule ^$ /fr/ [R]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} !^fr [NC]
  RewriteRule ^$ /en/ [R]
</IfModule>
```

Everything works, except one issue: I can not refresh page. It will show a 404 error. I guess it's because of the `.htaccess` settings.

What is the problem?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am currently stuck on the same issue

Comment: I think the official guide will help: https://angular.io/guide/i18n-common-deploy